# Dynamic labels for c3.js (also, label colors)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bar-chart, c3.js

I have the following c3.js code to make a bar graph that builds up from 0 (animates from 0 to the value of each bar).  The graph also has a label that animates along with it. The label shows the final value of the graph.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xbqypew/3/)

```
blankData=[
  ['data1',0,0,0,0],
  ['data2',0,0,0,0],
  ['data3',0,0,0,0]
]

chartData=[
  ['data1',60,10,4,25],
  ['data2',30,22,5,30],
  ['data3',30,9,4,17]
]

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    size: {
        height: 500,
    },
    data: {
        columns: blankData,
        colors:{
          data1:'#00af50',
          data2:'#F7931E',
          data3: '#FF0000'
        },
        names:{
          data1:'namedata1',
          data2:'namedata2',
          data3:'namedata3'

        },

        type:'bar',

        labels: true,
    },



    tooltip: {
        show: false
    },    
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['001', '002','003','004'],
             tick: {

             format: function (d) { 
              return "" ; }
            }
        }        
    },
    transition: {
      duration: 2000
    }
});
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load ({columns: chartData});
 }, 500)
```

This works nicely, but I'd like the labels to "build up" along with the animated bars. That is, the labels would start at 0 and increase up to the final value of the bar, as the bar animates.

Also, as a side question, would anyone know which attribute in the .css file to change to make the labels colored black? By default, the labels are the same color as the bars.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To change label colors - .c3-target-Tablet text {
   fill: green;
}

Comment: @NagaSaiA do you know which css file to add this line to? c3.css or c3.min.css? I tried adding it to the end of both files but the graph labels didn't change color

Comment: jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/8xbqypew/4/
i have used - .c3-text                     { stroke:yellow !important; }

Comment: for testing i have used yellow..hope this works for you :)

Comment: @NagaSaiA Looks great; thanks for the help with the coloring!

Comment: i am checking that dynamic label and update you final one :)

Comment: i am sure that we can do using  oninit , onrender and label format functons

Comment: anyluck in achieving your expected result? :)